# "Undefined" Text In SuiteCRM Instance Headings

Tags: database, undefined, crm, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I get the following error in messages, popups, headings, titles and even the loading bar on a SuiteCRM installation:

> "undefined"

in place of where the text should be.

In various SugarCRM forums it has mentioned the following:

1. Change permissions of cache folder to 777. --> *this has been done
   already*
2. Remove the file /cache/jsLanguage/en_us.js and clear the browser
   cache also. --> *tried this already*
3. Remove the cache folder by flushing the cache in Admin > Repair >
   Quick Repair and Rebuild within the Sugar application. --> *Tried
   this already*
4. Change the default values for dir_mode and file_mode to the
   following in the file config.php. --> *This has been already done*

`'dir_mode' => 493, // 16`

`'file_mode' => 420, // 164`

None of these solutions seemed to work.

Screenshots:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAWF5.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It likely not loading the JavaScript language strings as your .htaccess is not correct, likely the URL for your instance has changed from when it was first installed.

Go into Admin->repair and select Rebuild .htaccess File

Comment: Hmm ok then. That leads to a blank page. I wonder if my host has limited access to the .htaccess file?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/EfCXToJ.png which is what behaviour it usually has when it fails to load the page but isn't aware of it being an error.

Comment: Aha, Succeeded. Just didn't give a success dialogue. Which is I guess a minor UI issue?